# Runtime Permission Bug on Android API 28( i have to restart my app to display the captured image )

Tags: android, permissions, capture

so i'm making an app that allows the user to take a photo and then display the taken picture on ImageView .

everything works great for me , i'm following the new rules for android 24+ to access the external storage . 
**(provider is included in Manifest & xml file path)**

my problem is when i test it on **Android API28**

i can't display the picture if the permissions were just granted for First Time.

i have to restart the app for first time granting permissions to get the image path !

here's my example app :

TakePhoto Button :

```
private String[] permissions =  {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

public void onTakePhotoClicked(View v){
if (!hasPermissions())
requestPermissions(permissions,CAPTURE_PERM_REQ_CODE);
else
 invokeCamera();
}
```

handling requested permissions

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

  if(requestCode == CAPTURE_PERM_REQ_CODE && grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

       invokeCamera();

}
```

capture method

```
private void invokeCamera() {
        // create the image Uri

   Uri pictureUri;
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
        pictureUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),getPackageName() + ".provider",createImageFile());
         else
            pictureUri = Uri.fromFile(getImageFile());
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            // tell the camera where to save
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,pictureUri);


            // permission for saving the image
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

        startActivityForResult(intent,1144);

    }
```

createImageFile method

```
private File getImageFile() {

  File picturesDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);


  String imgName = "picture_JustForTest0X0X.jpg";

  return new File(picturesDirectory.getPath(), imgName);

}
```

on Activity For Result

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if (requestCode == CAPTURE_REQ_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){


     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getImageFile().getPath());
     ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
     imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}

}
```

Please Go ahead and Try it out with Android API28 , you'll never get the image for first time permission granted. must restart the app this is strange.

Comment: If you're just using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, you can remove the camera permission from your app entirely (it is only if you have the permission in your manifest is it required for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`).

Comment: yeah sure why not , but still having a problem with API 28

Comment: come one guys help me here

Comment: very surprised more people aren't complaining about this, or trying to solve this.